# open source/free web based proxy project

Tags: proxy, squid

is there any open source or free "web based proxy" server project that I can look into? I looking for one that don't required configuring browser sock..etc and having web basad interface. Does squid able to do that?

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

I used to need that several yeas ago. I don't think any supports SSL:

[**PHProxy**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/) - Supports javascript and cookies, but not AJAX or Flash that loads external content (such as youtube)

**[PHP-Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/)** - I don't remember much about this one, but I remember it not playing well with images.

**[glype](http://www.glype.com/)** - This is a new one for me, I've never tried it.